# Default selected text areas' position in response to Ctrl+F

Tags: javascript

While using browser's default search option(i.e. by ctrl+f), it highlights the matched text/s
crating a colored background area like 'div' or 'textarea'. It seems to me, the highlighted area are made through wrapping those matched text of the display objects of the html. If this is the case how could I get the position of those areas relative to screen coordinates.

Comment: The browser doesn't wrap the results in HTML.

Comment: post your code what you've tried so far

Comment: thanks.                                                              >>to F4r-20: Can you explain please.                                   >>to polin: Have not, rather searching as I don't know how browser do this.

Comment: @F4r-20 :Thanks. Can you explain please.

Comment: @polin :Have not, rather searching as I don't know how browser do this.

Comment: Explain? It doesn't wrap any HTML element. The highlighting of the text is done at an application level (By your browser)

Comment: @F4r-20 : is it possible to get its position in any means with javascript!